# отправка пустого калькулятора

Tags: javascript

допустим у меня есть калькулятор и модальное окно и я отправляю данные на сервер соответсвенно сумму расчета калькулятора тоже отправляю на сервер))как быть тогда если калькулятором не пользовался а key без value отправляется)) как не отправлять пустой калькулятор ??? помогите плз

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать `event.preventDefault()`. Вот вам простой пример как это работает.

```js
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submitBtn')

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const myInputValue = document.querySelector('#myInput').value

    // Проверим, если инпут пустой, остановим форму
    if (myInputValue == '') {
        e.preventDefault(); // Это остановит отправку формы
        console.log('Заполните поле перед отправкой');
    }
})
```

```html
<form action="" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="" id="myInput" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Send</button>
</form>
```